# Crash when wrapping latitude and longitude in map

Tags: mapkit, latitude-longitude

I get the current user map location and present it on a map with his location as the center of map.
It crash on the line

```
let currentLatitude = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
let currentLongitude = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!
```

with the error "Could not inset legal attribution from corner 4"

I think its something related to the force wrap for latitude and longitude. What shall i do to fix this error??

Here is my code:

```
// Location Manager settings
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

let currentLatitude = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
let currentLongitude = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!

//Map settings
mapMyLocation.showsUserLocation = true
mapMyLocation.delegate = self
let locationcoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLatitude, longitude: currentLongitude)
let zoomSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5)
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationcoordinates, span: zoomSpan)
mapMyLocation.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
    if let currentLatitude = locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude,
        let currentLongitude = locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude {

        //Map settings
        mapMyLocation.showsUserLocation = true
        mapMyLocation.delegate = self
        let locationcoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLatitude, longitude: currentLongitude)
        let zoomSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: locationcoordinates, span: zoomSpan)
        mapMyLocation.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: I used your code in  func locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations locations:) instead of viewdidLoad and it works fine for me now . Thanks a lot .